# Extra Buttons Showing on Tab View Controller

Tags: objective-c

There are 2 extra buttons on my storyboard tab view controller and I haven't connected anything yet. They only show up in run time and there is no code adding buttons to the tab bar controller.

Do you know where the buttons are coming from?

Comment: Would be nice to see a screenshot from your Storyboard file and from application when these buttons are present

Comment: They just show up during run time as item 1 and item 2 as is.

Comment: That means that you created a default storyboard for tabbed application and haven't bind anything. It's default file.

Comment: Even after I connect 3 other view controllers they still appear as extra buttons... item1 and item 2.

Comment: Remove them. When storyboard was created there were two empty view controllers bind to the main tab bar controller.

Comment: @user2759189 : **add screenshot..** ***that will help us a lot...***

Comment: I fixed it by deleting the tab controller then adding a new one. Then reconnecting my 3 view controllers. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the tab view controller then add a new one and redo the connections.